# Multiple on click events on document. Which is better?

Tags: events, onclick, click, document

Can someone tell me which is the correct/better way to do it?

```
$(document.body).on("click", "string1", function() {
    do function  
});
$(document.body).on("click", "string2", function() {
    do function  
});
```

OR

```
$(document.body).on("click", "string1", function() {
    do function
}).on("click", "string2", function() {
    do function
})
```

I've been doing the 2nd for a while now and it seems to work fine. But I've also been sceptical about it for some reason. Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: Both will be working in a similar fashion. The only difference is less number of LOCs. In JQuery the events are changed so called the "on" method will have the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my first opinion,
if you try $(document.body) double time then it will traverse again in DOM which is not good idea. So second example is good to avoid second time traversal in DOM

Comment: If my explanation helps you in any manner then please vote for me to earn some points atleast!:)